# Table not scrolling...data is recognised but scroll unavailable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use an **mCustomScrollbar** to scroll vertically and horizontally on my table. My code worked perfectly fine before but I am tidying up my jQuery and cannot see where it has now changed.

**Notes**

- I have played around in DevTools and disabled the custom scrollbar. After doing this, I set `overflow: scroll` instead of `overflow: hidden` on `bottomWrapperTable` but the horizontal scroll was still disabled.
- The table recognises that there is additional data in my table but still disables the scroll.
- I have the **exact same** code in another page and it works perfectly fine

**jQuery**

```
 <script>
      var recordID;
      (function(window, document, $) {
          $(document).bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              e.stopPropagation();
              var recID = $(e.target).parent().attr('id');
              recordID = recID;
              if ($(e.target).is('td')) {
                  $('#contextMenu').css({
                      left: e.pageX + 'px',
                      top: e.pageY + 'px'
                  }).show();
                  $('#contextMenu').fadeIn(500, startFocusOut());
              }
              return false;
          });
          $(function() {
              $('#fixed-table-head').on('scroll', function(e, val) {
                  if((-val >= 0) && (val < 10000)) {
                      this.scrollLeft = -val;
                  } else if (val === 10000) {
                      this.scrollLeft = (this.scrollWidth - this.clientWidth);
                  }
              });
          });
          $(window).load(function(){
              $(".bottomWrapperTable").mCustomScrollbar({
                  axis: "yx",
                  theme: "dark",
                  scrollbarPosition: "outside",
                  callbacks: {
                      whileScrolling: function(){
                          setScroll(this.mcs.left);
                      },
                      onScroll: function() {
                          setStartEndScroll(this.mcs.leftPct);
                      }
                  }
              });
              setInterval('updateClock()', 1000);
          });
      })(window, document, jQuery);
 </script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="bottomWrapper col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 noPadRight">
     <div class="row maxHeight maxWide">
         <div id="fixed-table-head" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 noPadLeft noPadRight">
             <table>
                 <thead>
                     ...
                 </thead>
             </table>
         </div>
         <div class="bottomWrapperTable col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 noPadLeft noPadRight">
             <table>
                 <thead>
                     ...
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                     ...
                 </tbody>
             </table>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**

If I remove the mCustomScrollbar code completely then it works. I may just remove the custom scrollbar and style the default one instead

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using, and what version is the site that it's working in using?

Comment: If you put in css `overflow: scroll` you don't need all JS that is scrolling programatically. You are making conflicts in your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a perfect answer if you still want to use the custom scrollbar. But a better alternative is just to remove the scrollbar and style the default one instead to fit your needs.